# How to apply a default value to an IgxSelectComponent

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

What is the recommended way to apply a default value to an `IgxSelectComponent` using a template like this?:

```html
<igx-select type="string" formControlName="classification">
    <label igxLabel>Classification</label>
    <igx-select-item *ngFor="let classification of classifications$ |async" [value]="classification">
        {{classification}}
    </igx-select-item>
</igx-select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably a good idea to also post the contents of your .ts file, with the form group and the classifications$ definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a default value to `IgxSelectComponent` using the `ngModel` directive and bind it to a global variable where is stored the required default value:

```html
<igx-select [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <label igxLabel>Simple Select</label>
  <igx-select-item *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
  </igx-select-item>
</igx-select>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/default-value-to-dropdown?file=src/app/select-sample-1/select-sample-1.component.ts) could be found a simple sample application that you could test on your side.

Also, a useful topic about Infragistics Select Component could be found [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/select#angular-select-example).